# Apache Shutdown unexpectedly (nothing seems to work!)

Tags: apache, xampp, shutdown

I've tried just about everything (expect for re-installing xampp) everyone's suggested doing, but Apache just won't run anymore on my setup. It did for a few days, but stopped randomly. I changed nothing before it's demise.

Here's my setup (& some of what I've tried already):

- I'm using xampp 1.8.3 (apache version: 2.4.9)
- Nothing else is taking up Port 80 or 443 - I've checked multiple times!
- I don't have Skype installed
- IIS isn't installed (nor are any other server related systems)
- I tried changing the ports via httpd.conf & restarting my computer
- I tried changing the port settings via the Service Settings in xampp's control panel configuration
- tried a previous system restore point (when it worked)

Not sure what to try next. Help?

Comment: If the XAMPP GUI isn't being helpful I'd look at the XAMPP and/or Apache error logs (if you haven't done so yet).

Comment: I did. Neither of those error logs have entries after 4/21. The last it was working was the 22nd or the 23rd & nothing seemed "out of line" in the errors right before the demise. Would a simple re-install fix the issue, or do you think that might not solve the issue? Is there a way to reset Port 80 somehow? (that may be a dumb question, I'm not really sure how this all works...I have little experience in these parts)

Comment: Assuming a reinstall is a quick process, that may be worthwhile.

Comment: Re-install worked! Phew!